# Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration :classpath'

Tags: java, dependencies, minecraft, gradlew

I'm trying to create a mod for Minecraft 1.7.10 and I am currently at setting up gradlew and other apps.

When, I run this command: `.\gradlew setupDecompWorkspace` I have this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Forge src'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:common:[3.2.0,4.0.0).
     Required by:
         :Forge src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:jobs:3.5.300-v20130429-1813
         :Forge src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:contenttype:3.4.200-v20130326-1255
         :Forge src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.equinox:preferences:3.5.100-v20130422-1538
      > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:common.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/common/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/common/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:preferences:[3.2.0,4.0.0).
     Required by:
         :Forge src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:contenttype:3.4.200-v20130326-1255
      > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:preferences.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/preferences/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/preferences/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:registry:[3.2.0,4.0.0).
     Required by:
         :Forge src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:contenttype:3.4.200-v20130326-1255
      > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:registry.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/registry/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/registry/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.core.runtime:compatibility:[3.1.0,4.0.0).
     Required by:
         :Forge src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:resources:3.2.1-R32x_v20060914
      > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.core.runtime:compatibility.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/runtime/compatibility/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/runtime/compatibility/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.core:expressions:[3.1.0,4.0.0).
     Required by:
         :Forge src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:resources:3.2.1-R32x_v20060914
      > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.core:expressions.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/expressions/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/expressions/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.core:filesystem:[1.0.0,2.0.0).
     Required by:
         :Forge src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:resources:3.2.1-R32x_v20060914
      > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.core:filesystem.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/filesystem/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/filesystem/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse:osgi:[3.7.0,4.0.0).
     Required by:
         :Forge src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
      > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse:osgi.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/osgi/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/osgi/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:common:[3.6.100,4.0.0).
     Required by:
         :Forge src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
      > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:common.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/common/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/common/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.core:jobs:[3.2.0,4.0.0).
     Required by:
         :Forge src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
      > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.core:jobs.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/jobs/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/jobs/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:registry:[3.4.0,4.0.0).
     Required by:
         :Forge src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
      > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:registry.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/registry/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/registry/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:preferences:[3.4.0,4.0.0).
     Required by:
         :Forge src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
      > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:preferences.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/preferences/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/preferences/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.core:contenttype:[3.3.0,4.0.0).
     Required by:
         :Forge src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
      > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.core:contenttype.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/contenttype/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/contenttype/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:app:[1.0.0,2.0.0).
     Required by:
         :Forge src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
      > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:app.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/app/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/app/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 17.807 secs
```

What do I do to solve the issue? Here's my `build.gradle` file:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven {
                name = "forge"
                url = "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven"
            }
            maven {
                name = "sonatype"
                url = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT'
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'forge'

    version = "1.0"
    group= "com.yourname.modid" // http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html
    archivesBaseName = "modid"

    minecraft {
        version = "1.7.10-10.13.4.1558-1.7.10"
        runDir = "eclipse"
    }

    dependencies {
        // you may put jars on which you depend on in ./libs
        // or you may define them like so..
        //compile "some.group:artifact:version:classifier"
        //compile "some.group:artifact:version"
          
        // real examples
        //compile 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'  // adds buildcraft to the dev env
        //compile 'com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:ejml:0.24' // adds ejml to the dev env

        // for more info...
        // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html
        // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

    }

    processResources {
        // this will ensure that this task is redone when the versions change.
        inputs.property "version", project.version
        inputs.property "mcversion", project.minecraft.version

        // replace stuff in mcmod.info, nothing else
        from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
            include 'mcmod.info'
                    
            // replace version and mcversion
            expand 'version':project.version, 'mcversion':project.minecraft.version
        }
            
        // copy everything else, thats not the mcmod.info
        from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
            exclude 'mcmod.info'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your gradle build file?

Also did you try to use the maven central in the gradle build file?

ex:

```
repositories {
mavenCentral() }
```

Comment: I share my build.gradle up !

Comment: Can you please just replace mavenCentral() with:

maven { url "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }

Answer (score 0):

Go to `C:\Users\[username]` delete the `.gradle` file. Then go to your folder where you extracted forge 1.7.10 and open gradle >> wrapper >> gradle-wrapper.properties and change/replace the last line with this - `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-all.zip`

Also make sure you have JDK 8 or higher installed and have set the path.